# Error on Uninstalling Exchange 2010 Hub Transport Role

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); if ($RoleProductPlatform -ieq "amd64") { $comClassFile = join-path $RoleInstallPath "bin\Monitoring\x86\DiagnosticCmdletController.dll"; $regSvr32WOW = join-path (join-path $env:SystemRoot sysWOW64) regsvr32.exe; start-SetupProcess -Name:"$regSvr32WOW" -Args:"/s /u `"$comClassFile`"" -Timeout:120000; }" was run: "Process execution failed with exit code 5.".

Process execution failed with exit code 5.
```

Operating system is Windows 2008 running Exchange 2010 with Hub Transport Role.
I have already uninstalled and re-installed the update roll ups (currently on 4 and only 4 is installed).  I have uninstalled the Microsoft Full Text Indexing Engine.

This server has been replaced and is not live, but it does exist in a production environment with live exchange servers, it is just not utilized.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951183/en

> This problem occurs because the DiagnosticCmdletController.dll file is unexpectedly unregistered before you try to uninstall Exchange Server 2007.

To fix this you'll have to register that DLL via regsvr32.exe.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.